# Iterating a knockout observable array in javascript

Tags: knockout-mapping-plugin

How Do I iterate an knockout observable array bound to data with knockout js mapping plugin ?. I have created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/shen747/CUJNe/) fiddle to demonstrate my issue. When I try to get the value of the knockout js array object it returns a function instead.

Could anyone please help me out in this matter ?. My Code is as shown below.

```
//Sample JSON Array
var data =
[{"street":"2532 Falkark Dr", "lat":"39.926295", "lng":"-86.012919",   "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8558 Appleby Ln", "lat":"39.922742", "lng":"-86.017637", "zipcode":"92256"}]

function ViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.addresses = ko.observableArray([]); 
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.addresses);

}
var viewModel = new ViewModel();

//function binding work order details to view
$(document).ready(function () {
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  gothroughtheObservableArray(viewModel.addresses());
});


function gothroughtheObservableArray(Addressarray)
{
 alert("Got Address Array of length "+Addressarray.length);    

for (var i = 0, len = Addressarray.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var address = Addressarray[i];
    alert(address.street);
}

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use `mapping.fromJS` it maps properties to observables.

In Knockout when you create an observable in order to gain access to it you invoke its function name.

So when you create

```
self.addresses = ko.observableArray([]);
```

In order to access the underlying array and iterate it (just like any other JavaScript array) you should do

```
var innerArray = self.addresses();
```

Exactly like you did. However, since each address is mapped to an observable to, you need to do that when accessing the actual properties of addresses.

Try

```
    alert(address.street());
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/39xCC/)

Answer (score 3):

You also could have just rewritten your function to look like this:

```
function gothroughtheObservableArray(Addressarray)
{
 alert("Got Address Array of length "+Addressarray().length);    

for (var i = 0, len = Addressarray().length; i < len; ++i) {
    var address = Addressarray()[i];
    alert(address.street());
}

}
```

This would have worked because as Benjamin answered to gain access to an observable, you invoke it's function.